# Javascript en WordPress onClick y opacidad

Tags: javascript, wordpress, plugin

Estoy usando [*CSS & Javascript Toolbox*](https://es-ar.wordpress.org/plugins/css-javascript-toolbox/) en *WordPress*, y tengo un elemento que cambia la opacidad con la `class="casa"`. Cuando hago `onClick`, uso este código, pero no funciona:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

     jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    var casa = $('.casa');
        $('.casa').on('click',function($){

               $('.casa').css('opacity', '0.5');
            });
    })
</script>
```

¿Cómo se soluciona esto?

Comment: Bienvenido a **Stack Overflow en español**, te ruego que traduzcas tu pregunta ya que si no será cerrada.

Comment: Hi, this site is purely in Spanish, consider translating your question into Spanish or migrating it to the site in English [so].

Comment: **function($)** los $ no van. Ademas declaras casa, y no lo usas. Y dentro del onclick deberia ser $(this).css... para que lo aplique al objecto que se le hace click y no a todas las .casa

Comment: @Roy es más que correcto todo lo que estás diciendo, gracias por contribuir... Pero publicarlo como un comentario tiene el efecto opuesto al deseado: no funciona como respuesta (la pregunta sigue como "no respondida"), los usuarios no pueden votar en tu solución al problema, e inhibe a que otros publiquen la respuesta correctamente por no copiar lo mismo que escribiste.. ¿Podrás eliminar el comentario y publicarlo efectivamente como respuesta?

Comment: @Joacer en cuanto a [esta revisión](https://es.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/44124) creo que te puede interesar lo que se discutió en [¿Qué hacer con esta pregunta en inglés, que fue traducida a español por alguien que no es OP?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1123/127)

Comment: @fedorqui ídem.

Answer (score 0):

En el atributo de la función que desencadenas con el evento click, estás pasando como parámetro "$". Prueba a pasar cualquier otra letra (que te servirá para tratar posteriormente el evento) y verás como funciona:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $('.casa').on('click',function(e){
           $(this).css('opacity', '0.5');
        });
    })
</script>
```

He actualizado mi respuesta

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">

 jQuery(document).ready(function(e){
var casa = $('.casa');
    casa.on('click',function(e){
            
           $(this).css('opacity', '0.5');
    
        });


})
</script> Y me da este nuevo errorUncaught TypeError: $ is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous>

Comment: me da este error Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> usando este nuevo código <script type="text/javascript">

 jQuery(document).ready(function(e){
var casa = $('.casa');
    casa.on('click',function(e){
            
           $(this).css('opacity', '0.5');
    
        });


})
</script>

Comment: Prueba de estoa forma:
`<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
  $('.casa').on('click',function(e){
    $('.casa').css('opacity', '0.5');
  });
})
</script>`
Y comprueba que has añadido jQuery a tu documento, porque si no no va a entender ni el $ ni nada.

Si no lo tienes añadido, hazlo con esto `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>`

Answer (score 0):

Si comienzas con `jQuery()...` en el document ready pasas el parámetro $ para poder usarlo dentro. 
Luego en el `on('click', function...` pasas un parámetro que contiene el evento por si lo necesitas dentro de tu función:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){ 
    var casa = $('.casa'); 
    casa.on('click',function(e){ 
        $(this).css('opacity', '0.5'); 
    }); 
})
```